# Could anyone find out what i did wrong in this prepared statement?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I made a prepared statement for DB access, it dosent work though.. I'm not really sure what the problem is.

What it should do is take a integer and a string and update the DB according to this.

Here is the code.
The connection to the DB itself works, this i know cause i can execute "normal" statements.

```
public void updateShipment(int shipmentNumber, String currentLocation)
        throws SQLException {

    String sql = "UPDATE shipments SET current_node=? WHERE shipment_id=?";
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    pre = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pre.setInt(1, shipmentNumber);
    pre.setString(2, currentLocation);
    pre.executeUpdate();
    con.commit();
    pre.close();
    con.setAutoCommit(true);
}
```

Comment: Well, it dosent send any update to the DB. Tested the sql itself inside sqlite and it works, dosent work through java though, no exceptions are given.

Comment: What's your exact problem? What error are you getting? Try to log the exact statement that's being sent to the database by configuring your JDBC driver to do so.

Comment: well if it is solved here @ SO you need to mark the answer that is the answer to question actually by clicking right mark near to answer

Comment: right! first time post here :) thanks for the info!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you get parameter 1 and 2 mixed up when you set them. Did you mean:

```
pre.setString(1, currentLocation);
pre.setInt(2, shipmentNumber);
```

Comment: Erhm, this makes me a bit embarraced... Yes it works now. How could i miss a simple thing like that? :)      Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

you mixed the parameters, this should be the right code

```
pre.setInt(2, shipmentNumber);
pre.setString(1, currentLocation);
```